# How to right align a table row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this table using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) and HTML (with HTML), and I want the row (Sum 0) to be aligned right and positioned at the last column. This is what I did, but it's still below the first column.

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Option</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
            $cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
            $sum = 0;
            for($i = 0; $i < count($cart); $i++){
                $sum += $cart[$i]->price * $cart[$i]->quantity;
        ?>

        <tr class="success">
            <td><a href="cart.php?id=<?php echo $cart[$i]->id; ?>&action=delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a></td>
            <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->price; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->quantity; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->price * $cart[$i]->quantity; ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>

        <div class="text-right">
            <tr class="danger">
                <td style="width:50%;float:left" colspan="5">Sum</td>
                <td style="width:50%;float:right"><span class="pull-right"><?php echo $sum ?></span></td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't need to a `td` float.

Comment: Please show the full structure

Comment: Are these nested inside a `<table>`?

Comment: you should close off your styles with `;` it's only good practice.

Comment: Yes sorry! Will do. Yes it's inside a <table>!

Comment: You shouldn't be wrapping a `<tr>` in a `<div>`. The only permitted parent elements are `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>`. You're going to have to provide additional information as to the **whats** and **whys** of what you're attempting to do. You say that you want the row (we're assuming the `<tr>`) to be right aligned. Right aligned to what? Details would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, don't provide the PHP (but **do** include the output of the PHP if relevant).

Comment: Edited OP to show you the whole code! OK so what I want to do is have the Sum of the Total be placed below Total (like all tables like this do). So the word "Sum" starts left-aligned below Total, and the actual sum digit (0, 100 or whatever) below Total as well but right-aligned. I hope I'm explaning this well, sorry sometimes it's hard for me to explain things well in English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an equal number of columns for your sum row as you defined in your first row. Either leave the first few table cells empty or use [`colspan` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan).

Adjust empty cells and colspan length as needed. You could easily include *"Sum"* and the associated value into a single cell.

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Option</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>#123</td>
    <td>Some Name</td>
    <td>$1.23</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>$6.15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>#456</td>
    <td>Some Name</td>
    <td>$4.56</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>$4.56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td><strong>Sum</strong>
    </td>
    <td><strong>$10.71</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't use a `<div>` inside a `<table>`. Also, you don't need any `float` value in <td>. Just make your `<table>`'s `width: 100%`. Have a look at the snippet below. It looks like this is what you need:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr class="danger">
         <td style="" colspan="5">Sum</td>
         <td class="text-right"><span>0</span></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However this is not exactly how I want the row to look! This is what I just wrote above: what I want to do is have the Sum of the Total be placed below Total (like all tables like this do). So the word "Sum" starts left-aligned below Total, and the actual sum digit (0, 100 or whatever) below Total as well but right-aligned. I hope I'm explaning this well, sorry sometimes it's hard for me to explain things well in English!

Comment: Something like this! (i just found it online): https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3crM.png

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on image, changed `colspan` from `5` to `6` and removed `div` containing Sum 0 Data `row`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Option</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      
       <!--<?php 
        $cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
        $sum = 0; 
        for($i = 0; $i < count($cart); $i++){
            $sum += $cart[$i]->price * $cart[$i]->quantity;
        ?>-->
        
      <tr class="success">
        <td><a href="cart.php?id=<?php echo $cart[$i]->id; ?>&action=delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a></td>
        <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->price; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->quantity; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->price * $cart[$i]->quantity; ?></td>
      </tr>
            
      <?php } ?>
         
      <!--<div class="text-right">-->
      <tr class="danger">
        <td class="text-right" colspan="6">Sum &nbsp;<span><?php echo $sum ?>0</span></td>
      </tr>
      <!--</div>-->
    </thead>
</table>
```